# Removing All Nulls From Collections

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm having to deal with collections of data being thrown at my application from data sources out of my control.  Some of these collections contain nulls which I would prefer to filter out as soon as they hit my code rather than scatter null checking code all over the place.  I want to do this in a reusable generic fashion and have written this method to do it:

```
    public static void RemoveNulls<T>(this IList<T> collection) where T : class
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (collection[i] == null)
                collection.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
```

I know on the concrete List class there is the `RemoveAll()` method that could be used like:

```
collection.RemoveAll(x => x == null);
```

But a lot of the return types are interface based (IList/ IList ...) rather than concrete types.

Comment: Please could you elaborate more why you cannot use `RemoveAll`?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The code you've written won't work, because removing an item shifts the indexes of all subsequent elements down by 1.  Every time you remove a null, your code will skip checking the next element.

Comment: People can be such pedants around here ...

Comment: @Jammer - You have a couple spelling errors, and it seems, you are trying to solve the wrong problem.  It sounds like you control what is placed inside your collections, which means, you can determine if that data should even be added to the collection.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of removing nulls from source collection, you can create a copy of collection without nulls using LINQ:

```
collection.Where(i => i != null).ToList();
```

Extension methods would work on any IEnumerable, including IList.

Comment: Why copy a whole collection needlessly?

Comment: @Jammer, you can also drop the `.ToList()` part so that it would work as a filter. If you care about performance, keep in mind that every RemoveAt will move all list items that come after the removed one. So if you remove 10 items from the beginning of the list with 1000 items, at least 990 items would be moved in memory 10 times.

Comment: It may actually improve performance, since removing elements from an `IList` (at least with an array backing like `List<T>`) will force the copying of all subsequent elements down one slot every time you do it.

Comment: @Jammer I'd recommend running some performance tests using this solution vs the in-place solution.  If you average more than two nulls per collection I'd bet this will run faster.

Answer (score 4):

Your method won't work because removing an element will cause the index of all subsequent elements to be decremented.  If you don't want a Linq solution (which seems simplest: see the answer from @alex), you should iterate backwards.

```
public static void RemoveNulls<T>(this IList<T> collection) where T : class
{
    for (var i = collection.Count-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        if (collection[i] == null)
            collection.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Testing it here works just fine" - try a few more test cases.  In particular, a collection with two consecutive nulls followed by a non-null.